# run time error while im show the data in list view

Tags: android

hi i m just facing a problem that i just build a demo application in which that calling a rest api and sho data in json in list view through AsyncTask here is my code and plz suggest me where i worng in code 
     package test.rest.api;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*; 

public class showalbooks extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
String returnString="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.showalbooks);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
       InputStream in = entity.getContent();
         StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
         int n = 1;
         while (n>0) {
             byte[] b = new byte[4096];
             n =  in.read(b);
             if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
         }
         return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.156/recess/document/document.json");
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response=null;
         try{
          response = client.execute(httpGet);}
         catch(Exception e){}
         System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
         String text = null;
         try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return e.getLocalizedMessage();
         }
         String var =text;             
         try{

          JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(var);
          JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("document");
             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getString("id")+
                             ", title: "+json_data.getString("title")
                     );
                     list1.add(json_data.getString("title"));

                     returnString += "\n" +"id:"+ json_data.getString("id")+" "+"Title:"+ json_data.getString("title");

                     }


     }
     catch(JSONException e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
     }
         return returnString;

    }   

    //@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results!=null) {

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(showalbooks.this, R.layout.showalbooks, list1));

        }

    }
}

public void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


  }
```

and here is log cat that show the error

```
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate   activity    ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm.contentprovidertest/com.google.android.gm.contentprovidertest.Main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gm.contentprovidertest.Main
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
 05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gm.contentprovidertest.Main
  05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
   05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
    05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
   05-15 18:27:19.582: E/AndroidRuntime(610):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: `showalbooks` might be a typo for `showallbooks` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write down your "Main" class in the manifest.
see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: i do this activity show only blank page not a list plz check the code  i think i m wrong in somewhere in code